# Errors with Vue Dev Tools, opening component in editor. [Vue 2, Visual Studio Code, Mac Intel]

Tags: node.js, vue.js, visual-studio-code

```
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Could not open CommunityNavWrapper.vue in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: (code 9).

To specify an editor, specify the EDITOR env variable or add "editor" field to your Vue project config.
```

I am receiving the following error when attempting to open a component in Visual Studio Code from Vue Devtools.

I have specified the EDITOR env variable or add "editor" field to your Vue project config.

Has anyone run into a similar issue?